# Can I create an object if I don't have all instance variables values available at __init__ time?

Tags: python, python-3.x

`Python3`

```
class testObj:

def __init__(self, val1, val2):
    self.val1 = val1
    self.val2 = val2

def __repr__(self):
    return self.val1) + "," + self.val2
```

My actual code has several class variables (12) and many calculations are performed on the data that exists in my list of already-created objects. I find myself needing to add another variable to the class, `val3`, which is not known at object instantiation.

Is there a way to add `val3` to the `testObj` class, but not pass a value for it when the object is instantiated, and assign `val3` a value later? What is the safest way to handle this?

Comment: Yes, you can just assign it later, but this may not be an advisable design.

Comment: I'll update the question to what is the "safest way".... thanks.

Comment: Yup, you can do that although not the best design.  Just make sure to remove the values from your initializer method parameters if you want to set them later.

Comment: Do you have a reasonable default value for  `val3` that you could set in `__init__`? You could then use the [`@property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) decorator and its `.setter` sub decorator (not sure if thats the right term).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I create an object if I don't have all instance variables values available at **init** time?

Yes you can. How ? As Kyle and user2357112 say this is not an advisable design, but I guess, given the code you have shown that what you may want is doing

```
class testObj:
    def __init__(self, val1, val2):
        self.val1 = val1
        self.val2 = val2
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.val1 + "," + self.val2 + "," + getattr(self, 'val3', '') #<----------
```

Which may be, depending on what you really want to do, one of the *safest* way of calling `val3`.

```
>>> tobj = testObj('a','b')
>>> print(tobj)
a,b,
>>> tobj.val3 = 'c'
>>> print(tobj)  
a,b,c
```

---

Another strategy may be to create a property atribute which actually get element from cached values, as follows

```
class testObj:
    def __init__(self, val1, val2):
        self.val1 = val1
        self.val2 = val2
        self._cache = {}  #<----------
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.val1 + "," + self.val2 + "," + self.val3        
    @property
    def val3(self):
        return self._cache.get('val3', '')  #<----------
```

Which would lead to use it  as follows

```
>>> tobj = testObj('a','b')
>>> print(tobj)
a,b,
>>> tobj._cache['val3'] = 'c'
>>> print(tobj)  
a,b,c
```

---

Another strategy mentioned by Paul is

```
class testObj:
    def __init__(self, val1, val2):
        self.val1 = val1
        self.val2 = val2
        self._val3 = '' #<----------
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.val1 + "," + self.val2 + "," + self.val3        
    @property
    def val3(self):
        return self._val3        
    @val3.setter                 #<----------
    def val3(self, value):
        self._val3 = value
```

Use case

```
>>> tobj = testObj('a','b')
>>> print(tobj)
a,b,
>>> tobj.val3 = 'c'
>>> print(tobj)
a,b,c
```

---

But all the proposed ways of doing what you say involve a default value, arbitrarily `''` here.

Comment: The last strategy, mentioned by @paul-rooney is probably best. I'll set the `val3` value to something noticeably odd, and use `@property` and `.setter`. Thanks to both of you for the feedback.